# 4 Electric baseboards connected to a 15A 2 pole breaker - two heaters don't work

Tags: baseboard, circuit, electric-heat

I have one 15A 2-pole breaker that seems to be powering 4 baseboard heaters in 4 separate rooms. Several years ago, we remodeled a bathroom (where one of the heaters was installed), and I removed the baseboard heater, capped and taped the wires, and covered the box (but left the thermostat connected). At that time, the adjacent bedroom heater would no longer work, nor did the thermostat.

In 2017, we completely gutted that same bathroom, and I removed the thermostat and boxed in the wires. Since then, another room's baseboard and thermostat no longer work. Did I cut all power to adjacent heaters and thermostats (except only the one room that works) by removing just one baseboard heater and thermostat? Will installing a new heater and thermostat in the bathroom activate the entire line?

[image: wiring]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

Comment: Surprise that any of them worked.  Usually one baseboard heater will almost max out a 15 amp breaker(maybe a bit better with 240v)  When you removed the thermostat, was it two wires or more?

Comment: If there were more than 2 cables in that box, that's exactly what you did.   Pop the cover off that junction box and post a photo of its innards, and we should be able to put you right.

Comment: More info is needed in the pacific northwest I have seen all kinds of connections that worked but were not always code compliant. Knowing what the voltage of the baseboards and if the thermostats are single pole can make a difference in the wiring.

Comment: "covered the box"... "I removed the thermostat and boxed in the wires" They are still accessible just by unscrewing the cover plate, right? You didn't bury the boxes behind drywall, or even worse, remove the boxes leaving wire junctions without a box.